# Two Windows 10 installs on two separate SSDs with change to boot time?

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot

So I'll be heading back to school soon and, since it's all by distance, I wanted to install two copies of Windows 10 isolated from each other to separate my school and personal life.

The problem isn't knowing how to install two copies of windows 10, or dual boot with two separate drives. (I see there are guides for both of those separately so I'm sure I can, with some research, figure out how to make it work) The problem is that every time I've done any sort of dual boot in the past, it's added boot time by forcing me to select an OS to boot into or wait for a timeout for it to select a default. I was hoping there was a solution where it boots normally to one unless some kind of interrupt is pressed during boot or maybe just be able to select to reboot into the other OS when I'm in one already.

I've tried looking a lot of stuff up but I've just been getting the same results and not sure how I should reword my searches so I've turned to you guys.

I'll be getting two SSDs for this *if* it's possible (and feasible for someone with beginner-moderate experience with this) so I'm not sure if that means anything. I also apologize if this is the wrong site to ask on, I wasn't sure which one I should use!

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate license to run two instances of Windows 10 on the same machine. Windows Home, Pro, (OEM and Retail) and Windows Education version (so far as I know) all fall under that rule.

Windows can determine another installation on the same physical disk is using the same license.

So as I understand your question, you cannot do what you are trying to do with one license. You will need to purchase a second license.

Comment: I have absolutely no issue with buying a second copy of Windows. I just really want to separate my school and personal life for sanity reasons. Besides, I was considering upgrading to Windows 10 Pro so I'd just buy a second Windows 10 Home instead.

Edit: To add, I did want to install on two separate drives to make them as isolated as possible

Comment: Windows Home is fine.  I prefer and recommend Pro if you can manage it.

Comment: Well I may just have to upgrade as well at some point then. I'll look into it but I don't want to ask about it in this question because that would be off topic.

Comment: Your question is reasonable in this forum.